# How to traduce ArrayList.add from java to C?

Tags: java, c, loops, arraylist, malloc

I was wondering if you can help me with this.

I have a loop where I read some numbers.

I want to initialize a malloc that will add each of those number to an array but we don't know the size of the malloc.

Can you help me with this?

I would like to do something like this. I know how to do it in Java but I want to do it in C:

```
int[] mark = {1, 2, 3, 4}; //how to do if we don't know the size of mark?

ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList;
for loop{
arr.add(mark[i]); //so, for each loop the malloc adds mark[i]. We don't care about the size of the malloc
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: well, why not start to write `c` and see what happens? Weird to write a question in java about c

Comment: Because I totally understand Java. I'm new to C and I don't know how to do it. It is 100% logical for me how to do it in java but I have no clue in C

Comment: @user13425812 usually you start with, let's say, ten elements (so `malloc(10 * sizeof(int))`), then write a function that adds to the correct place in the allocated memory range and keeps track of how many element you put in there and, when it's full you `realloc` it to, let's say, double its current size.

Comment: If you read the java code for ArrayList, you will see that it does not alloc new memory every time that a new element is added.

It uses a variable, like a top, that its used to control the size of the array(when grow, when shrink) .

You might do the same in C

Comment: @user13425812 have you done with it?

Answer (score 0):

Java(7) ArrayList implementation: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java

If you look to the *add* method, you will notice that every call to this method, checks for the capacity of the array(if it is full).

If it is full, it must grow(usually 50% of the actual size), line: *207*, it uses **value >> 1**, that is the same as **value / 2**.

After that, it just put the element inside the array.

This piece of code might help you.

```
#ifndef MY_ARRAY_H
#define MY_ARRAY_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct array {
    int* elements;
    unsigned int max_elements;
    unsigned int top;
};

void add(struct array* ptr_array, int element) {    
    ptr_array->top++;
    if(ptr_array->top == ptr_array->max_elements) {
        puts("Reached the maximum size. \tIncreasing ...");
        // grow, in java array list, the grow is 50% of the current size, 
        unsigned int new_max = ( ptr_array->max_elements / 2 ) + ptr_array->max_elements;
        printf("Current size: %d\n", ptr_array->max_elements);
        printf("New max size: %d\n", new_max);

        // number of positions multiplying the size of bytes that an integer uses in memory
        int* new_ptr = (int*) realloc((void*) ptr_array->elements, new_max * sizeof(int));
        ptr_array->elements = new_ptr;
        ptr_array->max_elements = new_max;
    }
    printf("Top: %d\n", ptr_array->top);
    ptr_array -> elements[ptr_array->top] = element; 
}

struct array init(void) {
    struct array arrayList;
    int initial_size = 2; // as java, the default init size is 2.
    arrayList.elements = (int*) malloc(initial_size * sizeof(int));
    arrayList.max_elements = initial_size;
    arrayList.top = -1;
    return arrayList;
}


int main(void) {
    struct array arrayList = init();

    int max = 25;

    for(int index = 0; index < max; index++) {
        add(&arrayList, index + 100);
    }
    
    for(int index = max -1; index > 0; index--) {
        printf("%d, ", arrayList.elements[index]);
    }
    printf("%d.\n", arrayList.elements[0]);
    
    return 0;

}

#endif
```

Ps, I am a Java programmer too. :)

Comment: I must say spaces around `->` are a pretty unusual convention.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Since I came from Java, I am not good with the C conventions.